# A way for an iPhone to automaticly login to a captive portal (auto-submit a form based on location?)

Tags: iphone, wifi, geolocation

The wifi connectivity at my office is behind a captive portal; before you can use it you need to select your classification and then login using your standard security credentials. Since we require 'strong passwords' they're not a real thrill to type on an iPhone keyboard.

In my dream world I have an application that uses the same sort of scheme that the Foursquare app does to suggest you might want to log into a location you've been to before. It uses the same sort of scheme the phone itself does to determine if some sort of login is necessary and, if it seems not to be authenticated, does the login by submitting the necessary form.

In my daydream world it could just look at what wifi access point I'm connected to and periodically submit the form, needed or not.

There's solutions like 1Password but if I have to enter a password to open it that doesn't really save me any trouble. Plus it requires me to pay attention and notice when the authentication has expired; since the new iMessage scheme seems not to deal well with our captive portal (Apple's servers think I am logged in and I don't get the message via text; instead they all show up the next time I authenticate or when I leave the office)